# H2-Database CommandCentre: CSVREAD skips loading the first(!) csv-Line of Data

Tags: h2

folks,

H2 skips/drops the FIRST line of the following csv-Dataset ... 
and I couldn't find a solution or workaround. 
I have already looked through the various H2-tutorials and of course skimmed 
the internet ...

Am I the only one (newbie - my "home" is the IBM-Mainframe) 
who has such a problem inserting into a H2-database by using CSVREAD?

I expected here in this example the CSVREAD-Utility to insert **5(five!)** lines 
into the created table "VL01T098".

!!! *there is no "Column-Header-Line" in the csv-dataset - I get the data this way only* !!!

---

```
AJ52B1;999;2013-01-04;2014-03-01;03Z;A
AJ52C1;777;2012-09-03;2012-08-19;03Z; 
AJ52B1;;2013-01-04;2014-03-01;;X
AJ52B1;321;2014-05-12;;03Z;Y
AJ52B1;999;;2014-03-01;03Z;Z
```

---

> And here is my SQL (from the H2-joboutput):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS VL01T098;
```

Update count: 0
(0 ms)

```
    CREATE TABLE VL01T098 (
                 MODELL        CHAR(6)
               , FZG_STAT      CHAR(3)
               , ABGABE_DATUM  DATE
               , VERSAND_DATUM DATE
               , FZG_GRUPPE    CHAR(3)
               , AV_KZ         CHAR(1))
    AS SELECT * FROM
                CSVREAD
               ('D:\VL01D_Test\LOAD-csv\T098.csv', 
                 null, 
                'charset=UTF-8 fieldSeparator=; lineComment=#');
    COMMIT;
    select count(*) from VL01T098;

    select * from VL01T098;
MODELL  FZG_STAT ABGABE_DATUM   VERSAND_DATUM   FZG_GRUPPE  AV_KZ
AJ52C1  777      2012-09-03     2012-08-19      03Z         null
AJ52B1  null     2013-01-04     2014-03-01      null        X
AJ52B1  321      2014-05-12     null            03Z         Y
AJ52B1  999      null           2014-03-01      03Z         Z
```

(4 rows, 0 ms)

---

? Where is just the **first** csv-line gone ... and why is it lost?

Could you please help a H2-newbie ... with some IBM-DB2-experience

Many thanks in advance

**Achim**

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify a column list in [the `CSVREAD` function](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#csvread). That means the column list is read from the file, as documented:

> If the column names are specified (a list of column names separated
>   with the fieldSeparator), those are used, otherwise (or if they are
>   set to NULL) the first line of the file is interpreted as the column
>   names.

Comment: OK, in this case you are supposed to "accept" my answer.